# From where to call Asyntask in Google Signin Activity?

Tags: android, android-asynctask, google-signin, googlesigninaccount

This is my google signin page:

```
public class SignInActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements
        GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener,
        View.OnClickListener {

    private static final String TAG = "SignInActivity";
    private static final int RC_SIGN_IN = 9001;

    private GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;
    private TextView mStatusTextView;
    private ProgressDialog mProgressDialog;
    ConnectivityManager cm;
    NetworkInfo netInfo;
    Context context;
    ProgressDialog pd;
    GoogleSignInAccount acct;

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        android.support.v7.app.ActionBar ab = getSupportActionBar();
        ab.hide();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.signin_page);
        cm = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        netInfo = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();
        context=this;
        // Button listeners
        findViewById(R.id.sign_in_button).setOnClickListener(this);
        pd = new ProgressDialog(SignInActivity.this);
        pd.setMessage("loading");
        // [START configure_signin]
        // Configure sign-in to request the user's ID, email address, and basic
        // profile. ID and basic profile are included in DEFAULT_SIGN_IN.
        GoogleSignInOptions gso = new GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_SIGN_IN)
                .requestEmail()
                .build();
        // [END configure_signin]

        // [START build_client]
        // Build a GoogleApiClient with access to the Google Sign-In API and the
        // options specified by gso.
        mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
                .enableAutoManage(this /* FragmentActivity */, this /* OnConnectionFailedListener */)
                .addApi(Auth.GOOGLE_SIGN_IN_API, gso)
                .build();
        // [END build_client]

        // [START customize_button]
        // Customize sign-in button. The sign-in button can be displayed in
        // multiple sizes and color schemes. It can also be contextually
        // rendered based on the requested scopes. For example. a red button may
        // be displayed when Google+ scopes are requested, but a white button
        // may be displayed when only basic profile is requested. Try adding the
        // Scopes.PLUS_LOGIN scope to the GoogleSignInOptions to see the
        // difference.
        SignInButton signInButton = (SignInButton) findViewById(R.id.sign_in_button);
        signInButton.setSize(SignInButton.SIZE_STANDARD);
        signInButton.setScopes(gso.getScopeArray());
        // [END customize_button]
    }

    @Override
    public void onStart() {
        super.onStart();

        OptionalPendingResult<GoogleSignInResult> opr = Auth.GoogleSignInApi.silentSignIn(mGoogleApiClient);
        if (opr.isDone()) {
            // If the user's cached credentials are valid, the OptionalPendingResult will be "done"
            // and the GoogleSignInResult will be available instantly.
            Log.d(TAG, "Got cached sign-in");
            GoogleSignInResult result = opr.get();
            handleSignInResult(result);
        } else {
            // If the user has not previously signed in on this device or the sign-in has expired,
            // this asynchronous branch will attempt to sign in the user silently.  Cross-device
            // single sign-on will occur in this branch.
            showProgressDialog();
            opr.setResultCallback(new ResultCallback<GoogleSignInResult>() {
                @Override
                public void onResult(GoogleSignInResult googleSignInResult) {
                    hideProgressDialog();
                    handleSignInResult(googleSignInResult);
                }
            });
        }
    }

    // [START onActivityResult]
    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        // Result returned from launching the Intent from GoogleSignInApi.getSignInIntent(...);
        if (requestCode == RC_SIGN_IN) {
            GoogleSignInResult result = Auth.GoogleSignInApi.getSignInResultFromIntent(data);
            handleSignInResult(result);
        }
    }
    // [END onActivityResult]

    // [START handleSignInResult]
    private void handleSignInResult(GoogleSignInResult result) {
        Log.d(TAG, "handleSignInResult:" + result.isSuccess());
        if (result.isSuccess()) {
            // Signed in successfully, show authenticated UI.

            acct = result.getSignInAccount();

            pd.show();
            fetchUserdataServerAsync mfetchUserdataServerAsync=
                    new fetchUserdataServerAsync(acct.getEmail());
            mfetchUserdataServerAsync.execute();

            Intent intentreg = new Intent(this, RegistrationIntentService.class);
            intentreg.putExtra("email", "" + acct.getEmail());
            startService(intentreg);

            //   mStatusTextView.setText(getString("SignIN", acct.getDisplayName()));
            updateUI(true);
        } else {
            // Signed out, show unauthenticated UI.
            updateUI(false);
        }
    }
    // [END handleSignInResult]

    // [START signIn]
    private void signIn() {

        Intent signInIntent = Auth.GoogleSignInApi.getSignInIntent(mGoogleApiClient);
        startActivityForResult(signInIntent, RC_SIGN_IN);

    }
    // [END signIn]


    // [START revokeAccess]
    private void revokeAccess() {
        Auth.GoogleSignInApi.revokeAccess(mGoogleApiClient).setResultCallback(
                new ResultCallback<Status>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResult(Status status) {
                        // [START_EXCLUDE]
                        updateUI(false);
                        // [END_EXCLUDE]
                    }
                });
    }
    // [END revokeAccess]

    @Override
    public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult connectionResult) {
        // An unresolvable error has occurred and Google APIs (including Sign-In) will not
        // be available.
        Log.d(TAG, "onConnectionFailed:" + connectionResult);
    }

    private void showProgressDialog() {
        if (mProgressDialog == null) {
            mProgressDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
            mProgressDialog.setMessage("Loading...");
            mProgressDialog.setIndeterminate(true);
        }

        mProgressDialog.show();
    }

    private void hideProgressDialog() {
        if (mProgressDialog != null && mProgressDialog.isShowing()) {
            mProgressDialog.hide();
        }
    }

    private void updateUI(boolean signedIn) {
        if (signedIn) {
            findViewById(R.id.sign_in_button).setVisibility(View.GONE);

        } else {
            //   mStatusTextView.setText("Sign Out");

            findViewById(R.id.sign_in_button).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

            switch (v.getId()) {
                case R.id.sign_in_button:
                    if (netInfo != null && netInfo.isConnected()) {
                    signIn();}else {
                        Toast.makeText(context, "Check Your Internet Connection",
                                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                    break;
            }
    }
    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {

        super.onBackPressed();
    }
    private static boolean doesDatabaseExist(Context context) {
        DataBaseHelper mydb = new DataBaseHelper(context);
        File dbFile = context.getDatabasePath(mydb.getDatabaseName());
        return dbFile.exists();
    }

    private class fetchUserdataServerAsync extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, String> {

        String username;

        public fetchUserdataServerAsync(String _username) {

            username = _username;
        }

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(Void... voids) {
            //  JSONObject jsonObject= null;

            JSONArray jsonArr = new JSONArray();

            jsonArr.put(username);

            return Http.httpPost(jsonArr, "http://xxxxx.com/fetchdata.jsp", null);


        }

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();

        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String data) {
            super.onPostExecute(data);
            Log.v("data received", "" + data);

            JSONArray arr = null;
            DataBaseHelper mydb = new DataBaseHelper(SignInActivity.this);
            mydb.getWritableDatabase();
            try {
                arr = new JSONArray(data);
                for (int i=0; i< arr.length(); i++) {
                    JSONObject jObj = arr.getJSONObject(i);
                    String id_To_Search = jObj.getString("id_To_Search");
                   .....
                    mydb.Add_Account(
                            recid, matdate, bank, userName);

                }
                }catch(JSONException e){
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

            pd.dismiss();
            Intent intent = new Intent(SignInActivity.this,
                    ShowAllAccounts.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    }
}
```

I am confused where i should call my `AsynTask`? to get `acct.getEmail()` I need to call in `handleSigninResult()` but if I call there `AsynTask` getting called every time i open the app. Actually i need to call `AsynTask` only at the time of first login...what to do any ideas...????

```
 fetchUserdataServerAsync mfetchUserdataServerAsync= new fetchUserdataServerAsync(acct.getEmail());
 mfetchUserdataServerAsync.execute();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use SharedPreferences record your log in status. And you also can use MySQlite to record it. When you open your app, you can judge your status,then you can choose what should you have do.